# How to express a function in terms of new variable?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, variable

I have

```
In[57]:= g[a_, x_, y_] = 
 Simplify[Limit[f4[t], t -> Infinity]] + 
  Sqrt[-1]*Simplify[Limit[f5[t], t -> Infinity]]

Out[57]= ConditionalExpression[(1 + a + a x + a^2 x - a y)/(
  3 + 3 a + a^2) + (I (1 + a x + 2 a y + a^2 y))/(
  3 + 3 a + a^2), (x | y) \[Element] Reals && a > 0]
```

Now I want to express the `g[t,z]` in terms of a new variable

```
z = x + Sqrt[-1] y;
```

I was looking for expression like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps that's the answe to your question

```
expr=(1 + a + a x + a^2 x - a y)/(3 + 3 a +a^2) + (I (1 + a x + 2 a y + a^2 y))/(3 + 3 a + a^2);
expr /. {x -> Re[z], y -> Im[z]} // FullSimplify
(* ((1 + I) + a + a ((2 + I) + a) z - a Re[z])/(3 + a (3 + a))*)
```

Comment: Should rather be `expr /. {x -> Re[z], y -> Im[z]} // FullSimplify` (drop the `I` for `y`)

Comment: Why? `ComplexExpand[z, z] (*I Im[z] + Re[z]*)`

Comment: The OP's definition is the usual `z = x + Sqrt[-1] y`. So for `{Re[z], Im[z]} // ComplexExpand` you get `{x, y}`. These are the usual definitions of $x$ and $y$ being the real and imaginary parts of $z$, and both $x$ and $y$ being real numbers.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Comment: When you `FullSimplify` you get the OP's desired form.

Answer (score 1):

```
exp = ConditionalExpression[(1 + a + a x + a^2 x - a y)/(3 + 3 a + 
       a^2) + (I (1 + a x + 2 a y + a^2 y))/(3 + 3 a + a^2), (x | y) ∈ Reals && a > 0];

Simplify[exp, z == x + Sqrt[-1] y]
```

> ConditionalExpression[((1 + I) + a + I a y + a ((1 + I) + a) z)/( 3 + 3 a + a^2), 
>        (x | y) ∈ Reals && a > 0]

Comment: I want expression devoid of "y" and "x." I have edited the question accordingly.